# DB2 - INDEX WITH SCALAR FUNCTION

Tags: indexing, db2, db2-zos

I have to define this index:

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX INDEX1 ON TABLE1
(FIELD1
,FIELD2
,FIELD3
,COALESCE(FIELD_DATE,DATE('9999-12-31'))
USING...`

The statement ends in error: SQLCODE -270 FUNCTION NOT SUPPORTED. 
i am using Db2 z/os V11

[image]

I do not understand!!!
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: There is Db2 for z/OS version 11 and a Db2 version 11.5 fpr Linux, Unix and Windows - which one are you referring to?

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher. My mistake, sorry! The version in use is: DB2 Z / OS V.11 (I have corrected the text of the post)

Comment: You are violating one of the restrictions. Look at each restriction and test if your DDL (for your table) breaks one of these restriction to  find which one applies:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n270.html

Comment: The problem is "A CREATE INDEX statement must not specify DESC or RANDOM if the index is an expression-based index” I have ordered fields with ASC and it 's OK. However, this problem does not occur on the DB2 LUW version but I cannot find references in the manuals.